# Apturl in KDE/Krunner?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, kde

How can I use apturl links such as `apt:firefox` in KDE? In particular, can I get Krunner (the run dialog) to handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. aprurl *does* work in Krunner, but you can't just type `apturl:packagename`. You have to type `apturl://packagename`, in contrast to every other apturl interface I've used so far.